# Make Launchpad Appear on screen with mouse

Tags: macos, dock, launchpad

If that's not possible, then a way to trigger the Dock on the screen with mouse without moving my cursor to the bottom of the screen is also an acceptable solution (I know that the launchpad appears on the screen with Dock)

Also i did see the [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/bw83fe/show_launchpad_on_screen_with_the_mouse_external/) about this.

Comment: which reddit post ? also, there's F4

Comment: @ankii this is the reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/bw83fe/show_launchpad_on_screen_with_the_mouse_external/ 
F4 dosent make the launchpad appear on screen with mouse curser

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions to meet what you're looking for

#### Assign Mouse Button

If you mouse has more than the standard two buttons (left and right click), you can assign one of them to Launchpad.

For example, on the Logitech MX Master series, there's a "gesture" button that you can press with your thumb.  Using the included software/drivers from Logitech (Logitech Options), you can assign the buttons keystrokes like <kbd>F4</kbd> to display the LaunchPad.

[image: Logitech MX Master 3 Buttons]

If your mouse doesn't have this type of software, there are a couple of 3rd party options you can use

- [USBOverdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com/) (Shareware; $20) - This will allow you to customize the buttons, wheels, switches and controls to custom program what they do - like assigning a keyboard shortcut to them.  You can use it for free but with the "annoyance" reminder. However, the product is good and worth the $20 for what it does.
- [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) (10 building blocks Free; $30 Commercial License).  This one is very powerful and you can control basically anything that has a switch - mouse, keyboard, switch box, MIDI device, etc.  You can create simple workflows like sending a keyboard sequence (if this is all you do, it will be free) or super complex workflows where the press of a button will do any number of steps (I personally use this)

#### Activate Dock

You can "move focus to the dock" (the technical term) with a keyboard shortcut.  *Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts*.  The *predefined* shortcut is <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts - Move Focus to Dock]

Comment: well uh the title of the question is Make the launchpad appear on screen with my mouse cursor none of these answers make it appear on screen with my mouse cursor...i do use controller mate and i do have a g502 with my target button mapped to launching the launchpad

Comment: Your cursor has to interact with something so either you click on the launchpad icon, or you do something else as I described.  I also answered your question about moving the cursor to the dock which is moving focus to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to screen saver settings and go to hot corners there is the option to do this by moving mouse to any corner you want. Can also add a command key so it doesn't keep going off.

Comment: using hot corners dosen't make the launchpad appear on the screen with the mouse cursor

Comment: Hi, Have just tested this and it does work, you use mouse cursor to GET launchpad and also mouse is available to use within launchpad. Perhaps is more an underlying issue with your system? What happens exactly? No cursor at all?

Comment: uhh the launchpad appears on the screen that i last showed my dock not on the screen with the mouse cursor